# Comet Chat SDK integration compile time error

Tags: objective-c, xcode6.4, cometchat

I am implementing comet chat SDK for ios. But unable to compile. It shows clang error.

clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

My xCode version is 6.4 and deployment target is 7.0. Anyone worked on [comet Chat](https://www.cometchat.com/) , even its sample doesn't compile at all.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your Xcode to the latest version 7.2 and above. SDK doesn't support backward compatibility for Xcode.